# Integrate Node.js with Symfony2 or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, symfony, push-notification

I'm developing a web application with Symfony2. I need to create a push notifications sysmte (like Facebook). When an user publish something, I need some of another users receive a notification.

I saw that Node.js it's the easiest manner to do this. But, I did some simple examples and all works fine, but I don't know how can I integrate this node.js application with my Symfony2 application, or really with a PHP application.

Anybody can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

*Please note that you've not given enough details, so I will respond as a front-end developer and not as a mobile developer*

Integrating NodeJS and PHP (in general) is not a good way since you need to launch both servers separatly, create the websocket server in JS while your application is in PHP and finally create a request (GET or POST) from your PHP to you JS server. Well, a big mess, so I'll expose my solution here under.

*Quick insight for mobile apps.* Well, technically, there's no easy way. You can use the Push "protocol" (http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Push_technology) with NotificationPusher (https://github.com/Ph3nol/NotificationPusher). I didn't used it before so I can't help you with it.

*In general.*
Most of the time when people thinks of Push, long polling will do the trick. For starters it means that the request is made client-side and the server don't send data & close connection until there's new data.

**How do you implement this ?!?**
Basically, you change the *max_execution_time* using *ini_set* or *set_time_limit* to a very long time for the current script and launch a loop (like a do..while) with a sleep and the check to your data inside. From your Javascript just make an Ajax call, for example with jquery: $.get. Just remember to remove the timeout and stay in asynchronous mode.

The only drawback of this solution is that you will always have a connection opened to your server which will consume a bit more of battery on a mobile device. If you have multiple types of data to receive do not hesitate to merge the calls and publish a *type* in your response data, since most of the browsers allows only 2 or 3 simultaneous connections to the same server.

Answer (score 0):

I sounds like your describing WebSockets.

Take a look at Socket.io, its a module for node.js.

Also there is a example at GitHub https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat

Interesting files for you should be the index.js and the public/main.js.

You can see the example live at http://socket.io/demos/chat/